# Determine when http end point stopped sending POST request

Tags: node.js

I have an IoT (Arduino) device that sends HTTP POST request every 6 seconds to my NodeJs server.
The data from the device is sent in JSON format.
At some point, the device stops sending data (let's say the GSM module got turned off or maybe the device got turned off for some reason) and I need to determine when that happens and output something like: 'device status: offline'
I use ExpressJs to handle the server functionality and I can easily handle any POST/GET request from/to the IoT device but how to determine when it's no longer sending POST requests??

tried to check if the IP address of the IoT device (it uses GSM module with a SIM card to send data to my NodeJS server) is reachable but I'm new to Node and I use body-parser so the request is automatically parsed to JSON and I'm not sure how to determine if the IP is reachable.

`setDeviceStatus`() is a function that updates the device status (online/offline) in a cache file/table in my database

```
app.post('/floraData', (req,res,next) => {   

    var jsonObj = req.body;

    var deviceStatusTimer = setInterval(function(){

        if(jsonObj == null){

            setDeviceStatus(0);

            console.log("device offline");

        }

        else{

            setDeviceStatus(1);

            console.log("device is online");

        }

    }, 10000);

    next();

});
```

Comment: what about using websockets (sockets.io, for instance) to send ping/pong requests to your IoT device?

Comment: you might as well simply store `new Date()` it in a var on each POST. then that's going to contain the last time it posted

Comment: i'll try it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket will be an easier approach. As @Gonzalo.- pointed out in the comment, you can send ping request from the server to health check the IoT device.

However, WebSocket has its limitation that it can hardly scale out if you have a lot of IoT devices. If so, building a stateless application, like what you are doing now, will be more suitable in long run.

Answering your question, instead of using the IP (multiple devices can share the same IP) to health check the IoT device, the device can send the `device_id` (e.g. MAC address, custom UUID, etc.) in the POST request. Whenever the server receives the POST request, it should store the `device_id` in Redis, for example, with the `last_online` timestamp.

Depending on your use case, you can build another application (e.g. lambda + cloudwatch) to check the Redis periodically for any devices which the `last_online` time was `X` minutes ago.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it. WebSockets looks cool, i'll try both of these solutions.